# Generating all multiplicative partitions of $n$ in time $2^{o(\log n)}$

Tags: computational-complexity

Is it possible to generate all [multiplicative partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_partition) of $n$ in time $2^{o(\log n)}$?

$o(\cdot)$ is [*"small O"* notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: Two first thoughts, not necessarily useful or correct. Isn't that bound essentially just $n$? I think you have to factor $n$ first. Then: why do you need to know? How large will $n$ be in practice (if it's a practical matter)>

Comment: This is a theoretical question. Numbers ($n$) are to aim for infinity.

Comment: We can assume that the factors is available from outside (eg from a quantum computer - Shor algorithm).

Comment: If $n$ is $k$-th [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) then just the number of multiplicative partitions of $n$ is $k$-th [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number). The $k\to\infty$ asymptotics of logarithms of these coinside, right? (It is towards the negative answer.)